# addEventListener does not work on dynamically created button

Tags: javascript

I'm creating 3 buttons dynamically. Now I need to add an onclick event. How can I make the onclick work?

```
var btns='';
var category = ["fur_", "fts_", "fas_"];
for(i = 1; i < category.length; i++){
    btns +='<button type="button" class='+category[i]+' id= "myBtn'+i+'">Button</button>';
}
document.getElementById('div').innerHTML = btns;


var button = document.getElementById('myBtn1');
button.addEventListener('click', function () {
     alert('Clicked');
}, false);
```

Comment: `getElementById()` takes an id, not an element type.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: that was a typo. fixed it. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all the button elements and add the click event handler using a loop

```
var btns = '';
var category = ["fur_", "fts_", "fas_"];
for (i = 1; i < category.length; i++) {
    btns += '<button type="button" class=' + category[i] + ' id= "myBtn' + i + '">.....</button>';
}
var div = document.getElementById('div');
div.innerHTML = btns;

var handler = function () {
    alert('Clicked');
};
var buttons = div.querySelectorAll('button');
for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    buttons[i].addEventListener('click', handler, false);
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/htn44c2z/)

---

Another approach is to create a button element in the loop

```
var div = document.getElementById('div');
var btn;
var category = ["fur_", "fts_", "fas_"];
var handler = function () {
    alert('Clicked');
};
for (var i = 1; i < category.length; i++) {
    btn = document.createElement('button');
    btn.cassName = category[i];
    btn.cassName = 'myBtn' + i;
    btn.innerHTML = '....';
    btn.addEventListener('click', handler, false);
    div.appendChild(btn);
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/htn44c2z/3/)